# Image from database provider not shown, it works on localhost

Tags: php

I made a website in PHP with a mysql database.
The website works perfectly on my localhost but when I upload it to the provider server the image isn't shown. When I check the database on the provider server I see that the image file is stored so that is not the issue, other than that i am lost.
Thanks you very much in advance!

The code on the php page that has to display the image:

```
<img src="ObjectImage.php?nObjectID=<?php echo $row['fldObjectID']; ?>" name="ObjectImage" id="ObjectImage">
```

The code in the ObjectImage.php document:

```
<?php
$nObjectID = $_GET['nObjectID'];
include '../Connection.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fldObjectImage FROM tblobjecten WHERE fldObjectID='$nObjectID'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$image = $row['fldObjectImage'];
mysqli_close($con);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Dump $image into a file (using var_export($image, TRUE), for example) both, in your localhost and in the provider server and compare the results.

Comment: what does the image src attribute actually show in your live server when you do view source?

Comment: Use the chrome inspector tool to look at the image on both the live and local,  from here you can see the img src of the element and ensure it is correct for both system. It is most likely the src path that is incorrcet. After this it would be an idea to `echo $row['fldObjectID']` onto the page to ensure itis being passed on both systems correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in your code is very dangerous. You have an SQL-Injection in your query. When you use mysqli then use prepared statements.

Its not the best way to store images in a BLOB field. There could be a lot of problems. Check your database encoding that everything is UTF-8.

Then check your logs if you get some errors. Its possible that you have an error before the header command. That causes an error because you have an output before the header is send and the image is not shown.

Last possibility `<img src="ObjectImage.php` that you have more directory entries and your Browser can't find the php file. Try something like this:

`<img src="/ObjectImage.php`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I checked the log and there was no error in it. I tried putting a test link to open the ObjectImage.php page (removing the header output first) to see if i get a php error, this is not the case. The file is in my result set (i did a echo on the raw file, wich generates a bunch of mumbojambo). It is almost like this isn't allowed on the server from my provider, since it works perfectly locally.

Comment: I checked the database encoding, i think it's oke but i am not sure.  MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for 2 evenings before I went away for a couple of day's. I was hoping to find a solution now that I am back at home, but no1 else reacted. Does anybody else have some thought, maybe Stony has some other ideas. More input is valued as I am starting to get desperate. I know the solution is not to store images in my database, but I have my reasons why I rather still want to do it in this way. Thanks in advance!